# How do I make my parent div resize with my child div using display: grid and flex?

Tags: css

```css
html, body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, calc(20% - 20px));
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.container .item {
  background-color: red;
}

.item .inside {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.inside-elem {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">
    
      <div class="inside">
        <span class="inside-elem">ABC</span>
        <span class="inside-elem">EFG</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
    
    </div>
  </div>
```

In the example above, if you zoom in, you could see that EFG goes outside the grid cell. I want the grid cell to resize with its child element while maintaining the given format. The issue stems from me adding padding: 20px, the grid cell doesn't resize on the padding.

I tried adding border-box but that didn't fix it.

Comment: You used a grid-template, with a constant width for each column. Would you be open for the div to wrap the content instead? Means EFG comes below ABC, preserving same width for each column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?  I changed your `.container` to `display: flex`.  It maintains the layout and expands to fit the content.

I also added `width: 100%;` to the `.item` rule so that it takes up the full available width.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  justify-content: space-evenly
}

.container .item {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}

.item .inside {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.inside-elem {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">
    
      <div class="inside">
        <span class="inside-elem">ABC</span>
        <span class="inside-elem">EFG</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
    
    </div>
  </div>
```